# How to change value via input and buttons simultaneously

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input field that takes numbers and i want to change the value by keyboard input but also via buttons.

The buttons work fine as long as I don´t use keyboard input.
If I type in 10 for example and add 1 with the button the value changes to 101 and not to 11 as I expected. On the other hand, when I decrement the value with the button it works correctly again.

How can I make it work correctly?
I would be grateful for your help...

```
const [maxAmount, setMaxAmount] = useState(0);

const decrementMaxAmount = () => {
    if (maxAmount > 0) setMaxAmount(maxAmount - 1);
  };

const incrementMaxAmount = () => {
    setMaxAmount(maxAmount + 1);
  };

<button onClick={() => decrementMaxAmount()}>
<button onClick={() => incrementMaxAmount()}>

<input
 type="number"
 name="maxAmount"
 value={maxAmount}
 onChange={(event) => setMaxAmount(event.target.value)}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type of event.target.value is a string. So your maxAmount is a string :
`maxAmount + 1 === "10" + 1 === "101"`.

To avoid this, you can convert your type with the Number() constructor :
`setMaxAmount(Number(event.target.value))`

Answer (score 0):

`event.target.value` returns a string value, so you need to parse it. So:

`+event.target.value` or `parseInt(event.target.value)`

Answer (score 0):

That happens because the `event.target.value` is a string `’10’` and in JavaScript `’10’ + 1 = ‘101’`.
To get the expected results you should convert the `event.target.value` to an integer before assigning it.

```
onChange={(event) => setMaxAmount(parseInt(event.target.value))}
```

The `type=“number”` only tells the browser how to display the input field, not how to store the value.